# can't use onBackPressed with webView Fragment (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, back, onbackpressed

Hello i'm a beginner in android.
I got some and many fragment. I would like to go back when i click on the back button of my android.
My fragment (in my ActualitesFragment extends fragment)  :

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Boolean isConnected;

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actualites, container, false);
    MainActivity.webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    InternetState internetState = new InternetState();
    isConnected = internetState.isConnected(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    try
    {
        if(isConnected)
        {
            GetHtmlCode task = new GetHtmlCode();
            task.setLinearLayout(linearLayout);
            task.checkWebView(MainActivity.webView);
            task.execute("myURL");

        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Oups, no internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Oups, no internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    return rootView;
}
```

and there my MainActivity with onBackPressed() (I tried a lot of solution but, it doesn't work)

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
   Fragment webview = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("webview");
        if (webview instanceof ActualitesFragment){
            boolean goback = webView.canGoBack();
            if(!goback)
                super.onBackPressed();
        }
   // super.onBackPressed();
   /* if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }*/
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I would like to go back in my web view when i use the back button, for example : my main page is -> url/articles, when i click in my first article i got this : url/articles/article-1 and then, when i use the back button, i would like to come back in my main page ( url/articles)

Comment: You should add else condition of `if (!goback)` to do `ActualitesFragment.goBack()`. Btw, your code is incomplete (e.g. Where does `canGoBack()` defined ?, Do you added the tag "webview" when starting the transaction ?) and i can't give you an answer with lack of details.